# How upload file from local PC to remote server using Nightwatch and Browserstack?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I'm using nightwatch and browserstack and I want to test upload/download functionality. It works fine on my local machine but fails on browserstack because it tries to find a file on that host instead of my local PC.
I know that since selenium 2 it supports uploading files to remove servers using FileDetector:

```
var remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
var input = element(by.model("fileInput")),
input.sendKeys(path.resolve(__dirname, "filename."));
```

Does nightwatch provide any features to upload local files to remote server ?

Also, as I understand nightwatch doesn't use selenium-webdriver instead it sends HTTP requests to remote server, so I think it should be possible to implement this feature by sending HTTP request if remove server supports that , right ?

Answer (score 0):

To upload the file using Remotewebdriver instance, Webdriver has a FileDetector module which helps in detecting the file present on your local machine and first it uploads the file to the Browserstack/any cloud VM and then to your web app. It appears that Nightwatch has no implementation of selenium webdriver's 'remote.FileDetector'. However, you may want to include a vanilla node implementation within your nightwatch tests for file upload. You may port your *browser* instance to selenium webdriver instance and use something similar:

```
driver.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector);


driver.get('http://www.fileconvoy.com/').then(function(){
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('upfile_0')).sendKeys('/home/user/file_name').then(function(){
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('readTermsOfUse')).click().then(function(){
      driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('upload_button')).click().then(function(){
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
          console.log(title);
          driver.quit();
        });
      });
    });
```

Note: you may need the following import/dependencies: require('selenium-webdriver'); require('selenium-webdriver/remote');

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch provides the ability to extend it with custom commands.
The bellow works for sending the file to a selenium grid setup.

```
  Actions.uploadFile = function(filePath, callback) {
    var archiver = require('archiver'),
      zip = archiver('zip'),
      fs = require('fs');
    var buffers = [];
    var getStream = function(filePath) {
      return fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    };

    // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
    zip.on('data', function(data) {
      buffers.push(data);
    });
    zip.on('finish', function() {
      postRequest(
        '/file',
        { file: Buffer.concat(buffers).toString('base64') },
        callback
      );
    });

    zip.on('error', function(err) {
      reject(err);
    });
    var filename = filePath.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
    zip.append(getStream(filePath), { name: filename });

    zip.finalize();
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

`browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());` does not work in Node.js.

`setFileDetector` is not a function.